# Pending edits notification shown even though I don't have edit rights, then goes to a 404

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just signed up for WP.SE, though I am involved with other SE sites. I am seeing a notification icon for pending edits, even though I don't have enough rep to edit questions. The notification link then goes to a 404, presumably becuase I have insufficient rep to access that page. What's going on? This doesn't appear on any other SE sites for me, including SU, where I have enough rep to approve edits.

[image: Broken]

Comment: For those that don't know what is going on: there is a new system in place [which allows low-rep users to suggest edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work). High-rep users get a notification and can accept or reject the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this should be fixed now.